# Ubuntu Corrupts BIOS on Ryzen 3000 Machine

Tags: boot, bios, reboot, data-corruption

I have a PC with an Asrock B450M Steel Legend motherboard and a Ryzen 3700X CPU and I occasionally boot Ubuntu from the live DVD. Unfortunately it looks like Ubuntu is corrupting the BIOS though. After rebooting from Ubuntu the machine will hang at the POST screen and refuse to boot or enter the BIOS unless the BIOS is cleared with the CMOS jumper on the motherboard. This happened several times with Ubuntu 18.04. I then switched to Ubuntu 19.04 and updated the BIOS to the latest available and unfortunately it's happened again. This only occurs after rebooting from Ubuntu and only some of the time. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Do not know about Asrock. But AMD put out a fix for UEFI that vendors then have to offer. You need latest UEFI from vendor and latest Ubuntu. AMD UEFI/BIOS update for Ryzen 3000 series
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good MSI has also put out BIOS updates last week as a "beta" though without explicitly acknowledging the Linux fix. 
 Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked

Comment: The BIOS I'm using already has that update in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of testing it turns out this is being caused by Secure Boot being enabled and CSM being disabled.  You change one of those BIOS settings and no more corruption of the BIOS during reboots.