# Bluetooth and wifi support ASRock B450 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

my system is a new build and I am having some issues with the ASRock B450M Pro mother board (bios version P3.90).  In particular I can not seem to find a way to get my wifi or bluetooth to work.     I have been searching around forums for someway to update my system with the right config.

I can't tell if it is my bios,  and I don't want to go the the effort of purchasing windows to test it.   This is my first ubuntu systems   (coming off a long term OSX addiction)

Other details:

```
#> sudo free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       1.8Gi        27Gi        89Mi       1.8Gi        28Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
#> sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P3.90
       date: 12/09/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3600C19-16GVRB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM 0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3600C19-16GVRB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: f
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 10
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
#> sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI. Some other issues seem to be fixed with that. Asrock B450 UEFI & Driver update to stop flickering.
https://pcpartpicker.com/b/t4KBD3
Asrock B450M Steel Legend - turn UEFI Secure Boot off
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183093/ubuntu-corrupts-bios-on-ryzen-3000-machine

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the EXACT model # of your motherboard... is it B450M, or B450M Pro 4, or something else? Also show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also what processor do you have?

Comment: The processor is: amd ryzen 5 3600X

Comment: FYI - No audio either,   hope that helps

Comment: Upgraded my bios to 4.30 - Audio now working !

Comment: Solved - Next time buy a motherboard that has wireless.    My first build :(