# The bios don't detect my SSD as a boot device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, bios

I have a SATA SSD in my computer "running" a clean installation of Ubuntu and windows. Neither operating systems are detected by my bios as a boot device.

In my computer sits next to my SATA SSD:

- 1x NVMe SSD (Ubuntu, detected in bios)
- 2x SATA HHD (Windows, detected in bios)

Motherboard: B450M pro4 - Asrock

What I tried:
I managed to boot Ubuntu on my SATA SSD from the grub of my NVMe SSD, but this is not the solution I want. My main system is on my NVMe and I want to boot that as fast as possible. When I want to boot from my SATA SSD, I want to do it manually through the bios.

Swapping SATA cables doesn't solve the problem either.

The bios detect all drives, but it doesn't list the partitions of Ubuntu and the other one as a boot option. Is there an option to boot from a partition that isn't listed?

I don't know if it is related, but I have this problem since I installed my NVMe SSD in my computer.

Comment: Many have needed UEFI firmware & SSD/NVMe firmware updates. Also Windows fast startup need to be off. And UEFI drives set for AHCI, not RAID nor very old IDE which you may not have  anymore. Asrock B450 UEFI & Driver update to stop flickering.
https://pcpartpicker.com/b/t4KBD3
Asrock B450M Steel Legend - turn UEFI Secure Boot off
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183093/ubuntu-corrupts-bios-on-ryzen-3000-machine
Vega GPU is built into the CPU, then the M.2_2 socket cannot be used. 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424099&p=13877199#post13877199