# Can't install Ubuntu (or any Linux distro) on Gigabyte b450 Aorus

Tags: dual-boot

I recently had to format my computer where I used Ubuntu for almost one year. Today I tried to install again and I couldn't at all (I also tried Manjaro/Mint). Thinking about what has changed from 1 year to now, the only difference I could think of was the update I made in the BIOS to install Windows 11. Looking at the Gigabyte website, BIOS v63 implemented something related to this and now I'm wondering if that makes it impossible to install any Linux distro. Does that make sense?
I'm using the b450 Aorus Elite motherboard, Ryzen 3600x, BIOS vF64b.

I already tried installing with Secure Boot disabled and UEFI/CSM  both disabled and enabled.

Some errors that I got trying to install Mint and Ubuntu:

[image]

[image: Ubuntu]

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: You've provided no specific or useful details as to what Ubuntu product you're asking about; if it's a current/recent product, or an older one.  Without specifics, or ruling out user-procedure errors we can only express off-topic opinions.  You should also stick to being on-topic, unless off-topic detail is useful & specific to your *unclear* issue.

Comment: its ubuntu desktop v 22.03 lte, sry.

Comment: Did you update UEFI? Many have needed that. Similar issues: Gigabyte B450 Ryzen needs kernel & mesa drivers
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408247 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2423649
 And others with same chipset but different vendors: MSI B450 Tomahawk Max & MSI Nvidia GTX 1080 TI UEFI update & defaults
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2450961 Asrock B450M Steel Legend - turn UEFI Secure Boot off
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183093/ubuntu-corrupts-bios-on-ryzen-3000-machine

Comment: @oldfred im using the latest bios available so i guess im updated it, im going to try those solutions tho

Comment: @guiverc i mean ubuntu 22.04 LTS, sorry. Im not currently using ubuntu, im trying to install it and having issues

Comment: Are you using a USB hub? Try without. Also see nouveau which indicates a nVidia card? You need to use Safe Boot and be sure to include restricted drivers during install to get correct nVidia driver.

Comment: Im not using a usb hub. Early today i remove my ssd and put on my brothers pc, install ubuntu all the way, use it and works just fine. when i put back on my pc, boot wont work. I give up, you won mb b450 gigabyte

Answer (score 1):

Both images appear to show that your USB controller driver (xhci-hcd) had some sort of timeout or hard error which it did not recover from and which could have lead to the kernel hanging there. The Linux mint capture also shows traces of Machine Check Exception(s) (MCE) which are also hard failures and more serious. Given these errors, you might want to disable USB in the BIOS and see if it helps or not.

If possible try to boot the Ubuntu image by changing the kernel command line with "usbcore.nousb" to completely disable the USB stack and see if it gets you further which would indicate that USB was the problem.

Chances are though that you will not be able to proceed much further with the installation given that your keyboard and mouse are likely connected via USB.

Comment: "Given these errors, you might want to disable USB in the BIOS and see if it helps or not."

Sry im just a noob, ill be able to boot from pendrive if i do that? also, im trying to dual boot on this computer, usb on windows works fine, could be a pendrive problem?